# What is the function of the gitk.cache file in the. git folder?

Tags: git, gitk

After using git for a while, I found that there is a gitk.cache file in the. Git folder. What is the function of this file? What can be used for? Is there any potential safety hazard if it is leaked out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gitk.cache`file as the name suggest is just a cache of your activities and interactions with your git account during push/pull/update... It helps make things run a bit more smoothly in terms of speed (and as any cache is intended to do)

No it does not have a potential saftety hazard if it is leaked. You can google for `gitk.cache` and you will find a lot of people sharing theirs.

There is not much on this topic explicitly shared online but here is what I know for certain.

I hope it helps

Comment: Just because many people share stuff does not mean there is no information disclosure...

Comment: True! But it does not pose a potential safety hazard